# How can I use a variable in curl call within bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have this simple task and I've spent a few hours already trying to figure out how can I use a variable inside a curl call within my bash script:

```
message="Hello there"
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "${message}"}'
```

This is outputting ${message}, literally because it's inside a single quote. If I change the quotes and put double outside and single inside, it says command not found: Hello and then command not found: there.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Variables are not expanded within single-quotes. Rewrite using double-quotes:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\": \"${message}\"}"
```

Just remember that double-quotes within double-quotes have to be escaped.

Another variation could be:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "'"${message}"'"}'
```

This one breaks out of the single quotes, encloses `${message}` within double-quotes to prevent word splitting, and then finishes with another single-quoted string. That is:

```
... '{"text": "'"${message}"'"}'
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    single-quoted string


... '{"text": "'"${message}"'"}'
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                double-quoted string


... '{"text": "'"${message}"'"}'
                            ^^^^
                            single-quoted string
```

However, as the other answer and [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) pointed out in a comment, this is not a robust solution, because literal `"` and other characters in `$message` may break the JSON.

Use the other solution, which passes the content of `$message` to `jq` in a safe way, and `jq` takes care of correct escaping.

Comment: Damn it! I knew it was something very simple! :)) Thank you. I will accept the answer as soon as I'm able to.

Comment: I like the second one more. I was actually close to that one. One of my versions looked like this `'{"text": "'${message}'"}'`. So I just needed the inner double quotes, but the error was not very helpful to get a hint on that.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly with messages that contain literal `"`s, messages that contain literal newlines, or any other string that needs to be escaped before it's valid JSON string contents. Answers using `jq` are safer.

Answer (score 14):

While the other post (and [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)) correctly points out that single quotes prevent variable expansion, the robust solution is to use a JSON tool like `jq`:

```
message="Hello there"
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --data "$(jq -n --arg var "$message"  '.text = $var')"
```

This works correctly even when `$message` contains quotes and backslashes, while just injecting it in a JSON string can cause data corruption, invalid JSON or security issues.

Comment: Even better, just pipe the output of `jq` to `curl` and use `@-` as the argument to `--data`. This eliminates a layer of quoting.