# Importing every line of a file into Elasticsearch with -POST

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, curl, while-loop, cat

When I run this command, it literally posts `$line` into Elasticsearch instead of the lines of file.txt

```
cat file.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do curl -d '{ "field" : "$line" }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -POST "http://localhost:9200/indexname/doc"; done;
```

file.txt consist of:

```
This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three.
```

This is Elasticsearch 7.2 on Centos 7.

I tried escaping `$line` as in `\$line` and `($line)` or `"$line"` 
but it POSTS the actual value of `\$line` and `($line)` or `"$line"`

Expected data to be put into Elasticsearch:

```
{ "field" : "This is line one." }
{ "field" : "This is line two." }
{ "field" : "This is line three." }
```

actual data put into Elasticsearch 
`{ "field" : "$line" }`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it similar to this question: [How can I use a variable in curl call within bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852784/how-can-i-use-a-variable-in-curl-call-within-bash-script) and answer.  Thank you @that other guy and @chepner

```
cat file.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do jq -n --arg var "$line"  '.field = $var'| curl --data @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" -POST "http://localhost:9200/indexname/doc"; done;
```